# SSH Python Script Closing Too Early

Tags: python, paramiko

I’m trying to write a python script to SSH into a box and run a command using the paramiko library. I am still in the learning process when it comes to python but the aim of this exercise is to build upon this program and use it in the work place. 
I have been testing the program and so far so good however when the script passes in a command to the Linux box and the command takes awhile to get output, my script doesn’t return anything. For example, I tested the script against one of our storage servers. The command I told the script to pass into the server normally returns an output showing the fragmentation of the disk pools. If I was to SSH into one of the storage servers manually and run the command it normally takes 5 seconds for the command to run and output the information. So I get the feeling that my python script is closing the SSH session before the server has fully ran the command. 
So my question is whats the best way of telling the script to hold off before closing the session in an attempt to get all the output back from the command? Below is a snippet of the code:

```
def ssh_command(ip, user, passwd , command):
   client = paramiko.SSHClient()
   client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
   client.connect(ip, username=user, password=passwd)
   ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
   if ssh_session.active:
      ssh_session.exec_command(command)
      print ssh_session.recv(99999)
   return
```

I tried adjusting

```
print ssh_session.recv(99999)
```

to different values but had no luck. I think I’m not understanding this function fully. I know its the function thats telling the script to return to the user the output of the terminal command but I’m not 100% sure what 99999 represents. I thought this was a delay.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
print ssh_session.recv(99999)
```

Tells the program to receive the response up to that limit of characters. So if the length of the server's response was 100,000, then the program would receive only the first 99,999, and not the last character. If the response is less than or equal to 99,999, then the program will print the whole response.

If you want your program to delay before receiving a response, you can use:

```
import time

# do stuff
time.sleep(5) # delay the program for 5 seconds
print ssh_session.recv(99999)
# do more stuff
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I tried putting in a delay before print ssh_session.recv(99999) but unfortunately I still had the same issue. Thank you for answering what the (99999) means!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with paramiko, but it looks like you are getting some sort of wrapper to the lower level socket object, and doing operations manually, even though the `client` object you got has functions to take care of this for you. `recv` looks like the standard `Socket` call `recv`, which is how many bytes to read from the socket before returning.

Based on the pydocs I recommend using `client.exec_command`, which includes an option for a time out. Here is some doc pages which may help:
http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.0/api/client.html

Comment: Hi Matthew. Thats great thank you, I will have a look at using client.exec_command and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

the `recv()` method used here is actually expecting 99999 bytes from the socket. If 99999 bytes are not provided within a certain amount of time (i.e. timeout) then the connection will be closed and you'll be given the bytes provided within this time.

This is probably what is happening in your situation.

I've written a script to update SSH keys in multiple servers using Paramiko. You can [check it out](https://github.com/VeriTeknik/sshkeyupdate) as an example if you'd like.

In your case, if you want the output of the command you run, simply get the stdin, stdout, stderr of the command executed in the remote session.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_session.exec_command("ls -l")
output = stdout.readlines()
```

Now you should have the `stdout` of the command in the variable `output`.

Comment: Thanks nukacolacolic. I had a look through your work on GitHub. I had a play with your suggestion and changed my code to be:
   `stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command(command)
   print stdout.read()`   and it worked a lot better. If I passed 'ps' as the command I get the full output but when I ran it with the defrag command it didn't work. I tried using time.sleep(8) before `print stdout.read()` but still no joy on it.

Comment: I don't know about the `defrag` command. Are you referring to `e4defrag`? If so, can you try it with `-v` so that a verbose output will be provided?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The command is a command belonging to IBMs Spectrum Scale SAN. The command is mmdefragfs mmfs1 -i the output of the command should show the fragmentation of the disks in the SAN